# Zendesk single sign on. Guzzle request

Tags: php, guzzle, zendesk

How to send Guzzle GET request for Zendesk single sign on

```
$uri = "https://subdomain.zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt=myToken"

$request = $this->guzzle->get($uri);

$responseClient = $this->guzzle->send($request);
```

If I put uri in Postman user will be signed on and signed in. However my guzzle request gets StatusCode 200 but user isn't signed on and signed in.

May be I have to pass some additional headers.